# Should I use the .es6 file extension for ECMAscript2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've looked through the spec, did some websearches (as well as on stackoverflow) and I can't find anything that indicates a change has been made to the file extension for ECMAscript2015.

I realize that only the syntax has changed and probably the .js extension is still valid.

So what I'm asking is this:

Should I use .es6 to indicate that the file contains ECMAscript2015 syntax?
or
Should I just use the .js extension?

I personally favor .es6 over .js. However, I want to make sure that there aren't any possible problems with parsing or w/e (which I doubt since it's all just plain text and the file extension doesn't really matter, just want to be sure).

Also I like keeping with the specs to avoid issues.

PS: I'd like to avoid personal preferences, I'd like to know if there are any rules according to the ECMAscript2015 spec that states you should or should not use other file extensions than .js.

Comment: This depends on the context. Usually you may want to keep these files interpreted as JS, at least by editors. For the purpose of wildcard/glob matching I would prefer `.es6.js`.

Comment: It's not as if ES6 was a new language? It's still JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File extensions only matter when you run software that cares about them.

When dealing with local software, that generally means the operating system needs to connect the file extension the file type for any application software that cares. You want it to do The Right Thing when you double click the file in your file manager or when you tell your editor's Open dialogue to filter on JavaScript files.

When dealing with an HTTP server, that generally means that you want it to attach the correct (`application/javascript`) Content-Type HTTP response header.

I'm not aware of any parser that pays attention to the file extension after it is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need to change file extension, `Ecmascript 6` is just a set of new features added to the previous standard `Ecmascript 5`, Ecmascript is also known as `Javascript`... what you need is just to know if your environment supports that version or not.

Comment: Read the question again please: "I realize that only the syntax has changed and probably the .js extension is still valid."